# Safety of using std::ptr::write_volatile for interior mutability in a Copy type (i.e. without UnsafeCell)

Tags: optimization, rust, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to achieve interior mutability in a `Copy` value type (for caching purposes).

The problem is that, as far as I can tell, none of the types available for interior mutability (e.g. `UnsafeCell` and related types, atomic types) allows for the `Copy` trait. *This is stable Rust btw*.

My question is: how safe is using [`std::ptr::write_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_volatile.html) and [`std::ptr::read_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html) for achieving interior mutability in this case?

Specifically, I have this code and I want to know if there's any gotcha or undefined behavior in this:

```rust
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct CopyCell<T: Copy> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T: Copy> CopyCell<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { value }
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        unsafe { std::ptr::read_volatile(&self.value) }
    }

    pub fn set(&self, value: T) {
        let ptr = &self.value as *const T;
        let ptr = ptr as *mut T;
        unsafe { std::ptr::write_volatile(ptr, value) }
    }
}

impl<T: Default + Copy> Default for CopyCell<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        CopyCell { value: T::default() }
    }
}

impl<T: Display + Copy> Display for CopyCell<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let value = self.get();
        write!(f, "{value}")
    }
}

impl<T: Debug + Copy> Debug for CopyCell<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let value = self.get();
        write!(f, "{value:?}")
    }
}
```

My goal is to use that to implement a local cache inside a value type (e.g. a sort of memoization). I specifically want `Copy` semantics (i.e. instead of `Clone`) because they have better ergonomics for what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is a sample usage:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn simple_test() {
        let a = CopyCell::default();
        let b = CopyCell::new(42);

        assert_eq!(a.get(), 0);
        assert_eq!(b.get(), 42);

        a.set(123);
        b.set(b.get() * 10);
        assert_eq!(a.get(), 123);
        assert_eq!(b.get(), 420);

        let a1 = a;
        let b1 = b;

        a.set(0);
        b.set(0);

        assert_eq!(a1.get(), 123);
        assert_eq!(b1.get(), 420);
    }

    #[test]
    fn cached_compute() {
        let a = CachedCompute::new(10);
        assert_eq!(a.compute(), 100);
        assert_eq!(a.compute(), 100);

        let b = a;
        assert_eq!(b.compute(), 100);
    }

    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct CachedCompute {
        source: i32,
        result: CopyCell<Option<i32>>,
    }

    impl CachedCompute {
        pub fn new(source: i32) -> Self {
            Self {
                source,
                result: Default::default(),
            }
        }

        pub fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
            if let Some(value) = self.result.get() {
                value
            } else {
                let result = self.source * self.source; // assume this is expensive
                self.result.set(Some(result));
                result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works on a first blush. But I would like to know if there are any potential problems with this approach which might not be obvious on a superficial level.

I don't have a good enough understanding of Rust's memory model, compiler optimizations, machine-code level semantics, etc., that could cause problems in this case.

And even if that approach would work for current platforms, I would like to know if I could run into potential issues in the future regarding undefined behavior.

Comment: Always run unsafe code under Miri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No. There is absolutely no way to have interior mutability in Rust without `UnsafeCell`**.

Your code is UB and [Miri marks it as such](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a33d70d102f44692943a19855dcf5b8c):

```
error: Undefined Behavior: attempting a write access using <1698> at alloc880[0x0], but that tag only grants SharedReadOnly permission for this location
  --> src/main.rs:20:18
   |
20 |         unsafe { std::ptr::write_volatile(ptr, value) }
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  attempting a write access using <1698> at alloc880[0x0], but that tag only grants SharedReadOnly permission for this location
   |                  this error occurs as part of an access at alloc880[0x0..0x4]
   |
   = help: this indicates a potential bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, but the Stacked Borrows rules it violated are still experimental
   = help: see https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/blob/master/wip/stacked-borrows.md for further information
help: <1698> was created by a SharedReadOnly retag at offsets [0x0..0x4]
  --> src/main.rs:18:19
   |
18 |         let ptr = &self.value as *const T;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: BACKTRACE (of the first span):
   = note: inside `CopyCell::<i32>::set` at src/main.rs:20:18: 20:54
note: inside `main`
  --> src/main.rs:51:5
   |
51 |     a.set(123);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

By using volatile you've just tricked the optimizer so your code "works", but it's still UB.

[People want indeed an `UnsafeCell` that is `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25053), but it is a problem to add it now as people are relying on `T: Copy` to mean `T` does not have an `UnsafeCell` inside. Perhaps it'll be added some day, though.

Comment: Thanks. So as of now Rust has no way to soundly implement what I want.

I ran into a related discussion https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/411. In particular, https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/411#issuecomment-1580211688 gives an example of where such an approach may fail.

In short, Rust is free to read any & ref to the Cell without restraints, which could bypass the volatile read. I assume even a Copy could fail to see the updated volatile write.

For my particular use case, this wouldn't be a problem, but this wouldn't work in general.

Comment: @RicardoMachado The discussion around `VolatileCell` is not relevant here. Even if we would have such type it won't help you. You need interior mutability, not volatile.

Answer (score 0):

It might or might not be an acceptable workaround to you, but you can leak the [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html)s (or any other such interior mutability struct) and store `&'static Cell<T>` so you have interior mutability with values that are `Copy` though at the price of leaking their memory:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct CopyCell<T: 'static> {
    value: &'static Cell<T>,
}

impl<T> CopyCell<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            value: Box::leak(Box::new(Cell::new(value))),
        }
    }

    pub fn set(&self, value: T) {
        self.value.set(value);
    }
}

impl<T: Copy> CopyCell<T> {
    pub fn get(&self) -> T {
        self.value.get()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can afford the allocation and indirection, you don't need any leaking or interior mutability: you can just hold a raw pointer `*mut T` and be `Copy` as well as allow writes.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean all copies share the same underlying cell? This seems semantically different than what OP is asking for.

Comment: @cdhowie interior mutability is only needed in shared contexts to begin with, if you want an owned copy you can always just make your binding mutable.

Comment: @cafce25 That's not quite what I mean. I think the expectation is that if you copy a `Cell` you should get a new owned cell that has a value independent of all other copies. That's not the case with this `CopyCell`, which semantically behaves more like an `Arc<Cell>>`.